# How can I force an underscore to be part of a word in my Word macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to write a find and replace macro for a very large Word document.  I have an Excel file that contains 4100+ rows of was/now data that I want to replace. I can successfully loop through that file to pull out the word I am looking for, and the word I want to replace it with. However, my entries all contain underscores. The problem that I am running into is that Word treats an underscore as a new word.  So, for example, I want to replace "apple" with "snow".  I would like the following examples to be replaced: "apple", "apple,", "apple.", "apple(".  I would NOT like "apple" to be replaced in the following examples: "pineapple", "apple_x".  I attempted to use wildcards, but what happens is in my example "apple_x", it will change it to "snow_x". Does anyone know how to force the underscore to be part of the word?  Thank you.

Here is the code I am currently trying to use:

```
Sub MeasFindAndReplace()

Dim objExcel, path, filename, i, objFind, objReplace

path = “C:\"

filename = "Test.xls"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = True

objExcel.Workbooks.Open path & filename

objExcel.Workbooks(filename).Activate

For i = 2 To 4150

  If StrComp(objExcel.Worksheets("Master").Cells(i, 2), "", 1) = 0 Then

    Exit For

  Else

    objFind = objExcel.Worksheets("Master").Cells(i, 2).Value

    objReplace = objExcel.Worksheets("Master").Cells(i, 3).Value

    RepeatMeasFindAndReplace objFind, objReplace

  End If

Next i

objExcel.Quit

End Sub


Sub RepeatMeasFindAndReplace(objFind, objReplace)

objFind = "<" + objFind + ">"

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

If Not Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then

With Selection.Find

     .Text = objFind

     .Replacement.Text = objReplace

     .Forward = True

     .Wrap = wdFindContinue

     .Format = False

     .MatchCase = True

     .MatchWholeWord = True

     .MatchWildcards = True

     .MatchSoundsLike = False

     .MatchAllWordForms = False

End With

Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there only one word per cell?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ReplaceJamieLannister()

    Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    For Each Cell In rng2
    If Left(Cell.Value, 1) = "J" And Mid(Cell.Value, 6, 1) <> "_" Then


    Cell.Replace "Jamie", "King Slayer", xlPart

    End If

    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Data Before:

```
Jamie
Jamie,
Jamie)
Jamie.
Jamie_Lannister
PineJamie
```

Data After:

```
King Slayer
King Slayer,
King Slayer)
King Slayer.
Jamie_Lannister
PineJamie
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do this, not sure it's the best way to do it, but it seems to work JUST fine!

Here's what my code **produces** :

[image]

Here's the **code** :

```
Sub SuperReplace()

last = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 1 To last

    replacein = Cells(x, 1)
    replacewhat = Cells(x, 2)
    replacewith = Cells(x, 3)

    If replacein Like "*" & replacewhat & "*" And _
        InStr(replacein, "_") = 0 Then

        replacein = Replace(replacein, replacewhat, replacewith)
        Cells(x, 5) = replacein

    End If

Next

End Sub
```